# Change selection without id

Tags: selection

How can I change the selection? No ID or something in select tag.

```html
<label class="Select__select__3sjwOXNYT2 EventList__pageSize__YFgjEw1xbV"
  >Einträge: 25
  <select>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: *in Javascript*

Answer (score 1):

```
 var element = document.getElementsByClassName("the name of the class");
```

you can pass as many class name you want, the above statement returns an array of elements of the given type...

```
    DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    
    <label class="first">Einträge: 25
        <select>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
        </label>
    
   
    
    
    <script>
    [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('first'), function(el) {
        el.style.color= 'green';
    });

    </script>
this line is another way u can select the classname
    <script>
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('first');

Array.from(boxes).forEach(v => v.style.background = 'red');



    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This should help you select the classname

Answer (score 0):

I know that, but that doesnt help me.

I tried

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Select__select__3sjwOXNYT2 EventList__pageSize__YFgjEw1xbV")[0].options[1].selected = true
```

And

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Select__select__3sjwOXNYT2 EventList__pageSize__YFgjEw1xbV")[0].selectedIndex = 1
```

but nothing select.

Comment: you really not clear with what you want to achieve, what type of effect do you want to have on the class or tag.

Comment: Hm what you mean? The HTML code is not mine, I only try to select another option with my programm with JavaScript.

Comment: Oh no i dont mean like select with mouse or color, I mean the option (100), sorry